# MongoDb Streaming Out Inserted Data in Real-time (or near real-time)

Tags: java, mongodb, streaming, real-time, nosql

I have a number of MongoDB collections which take a number of JSON documents from various streaming sources. In other-words there a a number of processes which are continually inserting data into a set of MongoDB collections.

I need a way to stream the data out of MongoDB into downstream applications. So I want an system that conceptually looks like this:

```
App Stream1 --> 
App Stream2 -->     MONGODB     --->  Aggregated Stream
App Stream3 -->
```

OR this:

```
App Stream1 -->                 --->  MongoD Stream1
App Stream2 -->     MONGODB     --->  MongoD Stream2
App Stream3 -->                 --->  MongoD Stream3
```

The question is how do I stream data out of Mongo without having to continually poll/query the database?

The obvious question answer would be "why dont you change those app streaming processes to send messages to a Queue like Rabbit, Zero or ActiveMQ which then has them send to your Mongo Streaming processes and Mongo at once like this":

```
                 MONGODB
                   /|\  
                    |
App Stream1 -->     |          --->  MongoD Stream1
App Stream2 -->  SomeMQqueue   --->  MongoD Stream2
App Stream3 -->                --->  MongoD Stream3
```

In an ideal world yes that would be good, but we need Mongo to ensure that messages are saved first, to avoid duplicates and ensure that IDs are all generated etc. Mongo has to sit in the middle as the persistence layer.

So how do I stream messages out of a Mongo collection (not using GridFS etc) into these down stream apps. The basic school of thought has been to just poll for new documents and each document that is collected update it by adding another field to the JSON documents stored in the database, much like a process flag in a SQL table that stores a processed time stamp. I.e. every 1 second poll for documents where processed == null.... add processed = now().... update document.

Is there a neater/more computationally efficient method?

FYI - These are all Java processes.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing to a capped collection (or collections), you can use a [tailablecursor](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors) to push new data on the stream, or on a message queue from where it can be streamed out. However this will not work for a non-capped collection though.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sadly not using capped collections, not a bad feature though for a messaging service. Sounds like a index on processed flag and polling is the only option... If an index item is null is it still referenced in the index or does querying for null still mean collection scans?

Comment: Or I spoze we could have a capped collection at a fixed size act like a cache, then pull the items out one buy 1 and put them back into an ordinary collection. The question then becomes how do we save our position cursor between app runs? I'm assuming we just use a Mongo auto generated _id field and select everything greater than that ID field... Are all mongo generated _IDs in increasing order?

Comment: Indexes do store entries for `null`. If you're tailing a capped collection, you do need to store the last entry you saw (you can store this however you want, using another mongo collection will work fine), and then begin your tailable cursor at that element using `$min` and `skip(1)` to resume. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24minand%24max

Comment: Also note you'll want to ensure your capped collection is big enough to hold all the documents you might receive during a reasonable window of downtime on the application tailing that collection. If the capped collection is too small, you could lose documents, from the perspective of your queue.

Comment: There are ways to interpret the oplog (which is a capped collection too) but then it'd have to be done on the master, but I have not really looked much into it. Maybe something to look at. Please keep us posted on how things go btw, as its an interesting problem.

Comment: Also check my blog about this: http://www.warski.org/blog/2012/11/event-streaming-with-mongodb/