# Near Real time streaming data from Mongo DB to Datawarehouse

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-s3, stream, apache-kafka

We have a number MongoDB collections which will store data generated from the application(E-Commerce Order update, delivery, cancel, new orders etc).Currently, we are following traditional ETL approach to schedule data pull (Covert to file in s3/Staging load) and load to DW.As data volume is increasing we feel like it's an inefficient way since we are lagging at least one day to generate reports compared to real time streaming /similar kind of new ETL approaches.So as a streaming option first I read about Apache Kafka which is very popular.But the biggest challenge facing is how to convert this Mongo DB collection to Kafka topics.
I read this [MongoDb Streaming Out Inserted Data in Real-time (or near real-time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170384/mongodb-streaming-out-inserted-data-in-real-time-or-near-real-time). We are not using capped collections so that recommended solution won't work for us.

Can MongoDB collection be a Kafka producer?
Is there any better way to pull data from MongoDB realtime /near realtime to Target DB /s3 other than Kafka 
Note: I prefer a python solution which can easily integrate into our current workflow than Java/Scala.

Thanks